# Bounty question not visible on *Featured* tab

Tags: bug, bounty

I offered bounty on one of my own questions. I was expecting it to be on the ***Fetaured*** tab. But it fails to show up there. As per the FAQ a question with a bounty is supposed to be visible there.

Here is the link to the question:

[Two fluids flowing perpendicular in thermal contact with a Wall [Help to mathematically model]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117489/two-fluids-flowing-perpendicular-in-thermal-contact-with-a-wall-help-to-mathema)

Is there any explanation for this? Is it ususal or am I missing something here.

Comment: it's visible to me (I am using phone)

Comment: Sometimes the feature tab doesn't show the entire list of questions.

Comment: @YuiToCheng I will admit that I have just tried it to see using my desktop where I am logged in my account. Thanks for the clarification. maybe it is only visible in the feature tab from a separate account.

Comment: I see it as the last item of the first page of featured questions with my settings (listing 50 items at a time).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The issue was with my browser. Have now resolved it. Thanks